# Rails 3 Problem with Routes Constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, constraints

I'm trying to make it so that I can have a urls like this:

```
/events
/events/sunday # => The day is optional
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working even though I know it is getting called. It is at the bottom of my routes file.

```
match '/:post(/:day_filter)' => 'posts#index', :as => post_day_filter, :constraints => DayFilter.new 


class DayFilter

    def initialize
        @days = %w[all today tomorrow sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday]
    end

    def matches?(request)
        return @days.include?(request.params[:day_filter]) if request.params[:day_filter]
        true
    end

end
```

Here is my rake routes output:

```
post_day_filter        /:post(/:day_filter)(.:format)          {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is a little vague. Care to expound on that? Sharing the output of `rake routes` is always helpful for routing-related problems. ;)

Comment: I pasted it, though I don't think it will be too helpful. It's already at the bottom of my routes file and I've placed the debugger inside my constraint object to make sure it's getting called, and it is. It even seems to be returning the correct values.

Comment: What is/isn't happening unexpectedly? I'm assuming that your requests to "/events/sunday" are returning 404s, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It's not a 404, the routes are not being bypassed if the second parameter is not a day. if I type in `events/xyz` then params looks like {"post"=>"events", "day_filter"=>"xyz"}

Comment: It might not be this route hitting. Do you have another route that matches "events/:id", by chance? If you want to upload your routes to a Gist and share the link that'd be helpful.

Comment: I only have `:constraints => DayFilter.new` on exactly one route

Comment: I mean that you might have another route that is less particular about the second parameter that will match a request to '/events/foobar' and take `foobar` in as maybe an id parameter. E.g: `resources :events` or `get '/events/:id'`.

Comment: I don't, also, I've place a `debugger` inside the `matches?` method. The route is at the bottom of my routes file.

Comment: Another odd thing is that if I change my matches method to this: `def matches?(request); false; end` it gets bypassed every time.

Comment: Try calling it manually in console with a stub object: `class Foo; def params; { :day_of_week => 'foo' }; end; end; ValidDayOfWeek.matches?(Foo.new)`

Comment: This works just fine, but the route is still failing, very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, specifically, but the following is a much more performance-friendly way of doing the same thing:

```
class ValidDayOfWeek
  VALID_DAYS = %w[all today tomorrow sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday]
  def self.matches?(request)
    VALID_DAYS.include? request.params[:day_of_week]
  end
end

get ':/post_type(/:day_of_week)' => 'posts#index', :constraints => ValidDayOfWeek
```

The biggest difference is that this avoids initializing a new ValidDayOfWeek object on every request. The Rails guide gives an example where you *might* want a fresh object each time (real-time blacklist updating), but it's misleading for cases like yours.

Also, you were getting a bit verbose in your `matches?` method — no need for explicit returns or a conditional, as `includes?` will return either true or false as is.

Comment: Good performance tips, I didn't realize that about `initialize`. Also you have a typo on `(:/day_of_week)`

Comment: One thing to remember is that the day_of_week is optional. So the way you've re-written it won't work because a nil value is perfectly okay.

Comment: It looks like the problem actually had nothing to do with my validation class and I may have actually found a Rails bug.