# Urls with params cause request to be routed to wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm having a strange problem with my rails routing, when I go to the apps index path it's fine but if the index path has any routes it doesn't work. I have a controller that looks something like:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @things = Thing.search params[:q]
  end

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

Pretty generic in my opinion, the search method takes the `:q` param as its input, here is my routes:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "things#index"
  resources :things
end
```

Any thoughts at why this is happening?

Comment: I've noticed something very similar when trying to play with routes around the `root` directive where the resources and `root` share the same controller. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313905/rails-3-problem-with-routes-constraint I swear it's a bug. I should update my actual solution, but I basically ended up hardcoding all the paths, since there were about 20, I figured I could get away with it.

Comment: @Dex, yah man it's so strange I suppose I'll have to use your method for working around this for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a custom route that passes 'q' along to the controller:

```
resources :things
map.connect '/things/:q', :controller => :things, :q => :q
root :to => "things#index"
```

It will match the top first, then move down if it doesn't exist. Then you can call params[:q] no problem.

Comment: Yup, [sighs] I sort of figured this is what I was going to have to do, it's so strange, it must be a bug of some sorts, or maybe something to do with that `search` method. Oh well, thanks for the help.